# Where can we find the definition of methods present in the interfaces given by java.util package

Tags: java, interface

java doesn't allow definition of methods in interface (until 1.7) but for example in `List<>` interface there are methods such as `size()`, `conatins()`, `isEmpty()`. I wonder where is its definition. Since it is an interface we need to define these methods while we use it in our class. So can anyone tell me where is it defined?

Comment: It is defined in whatever implementation of list you are actually using - `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc...

Comment: It depends on the implementing class. The whole point of an interface it not to contain an implementation. Take a look at "All Known Implementing Classes" [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to see which of java's built-in classes implement that interface.

Comment: When you say "definition" of a method, do you mean its "declaration" *(method signature only, no body)* or its "implementation" *(body of the method)*? Please use correct terminology, to avoid misunderstanding of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several concrete classes that implement the `List` interface in the `java.util` package. Looking at [`List`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) lists a few of them under the "All Known Implementing Classes" heading. You'll find the implementations there.